# Extended variants not working in Tailwind 2.0.2 and Laravel 8

Tags: css, laravel, tailwind-css, extend, variant

I am using Tailwind CSS version 2.0.2 in a Laravel 8.44.0 project.
I am simply just trying to add some styling to my active menu tabs.

Here are my variants in tailwind.config.js:

```
    variants: {
        extend: {
            opacity: ['disabled'],
            backgroundColor: ['active'],
            borderColor: ['active'],
        },
    },
```

then on my page I have links that I want to style when they are active, like this:

```
<a href="#packages" class="navigation__link border-b-2 bg-white border-gray-200 active:border-red-500 active:bg-red-200 active">
                        Packages
                    </a>
```

But the styling is not applied when the link is active. The link background stays white and the bottom border stays gray.

Is there anything I was supposed to do to generate the newly added variants?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <script>
    tailwind.config = {
      variants: {
        extend: {
          opacity: ['disabled'],
          backgroundColor: ['active'],
          borderColor: ['active']
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#packages" class="navigation__link border-b-2 bg-white border-gray-200 active:border-red-500 active:bg-red-200 active">
    Packages
  </a>
</body>

</html>
```

However, i believe youre misunderstanding the `:active` pseudoclass.

`:active` is present while youre holding down the mouse-click on the link. It will deactivate the moment you let go.
Adding the css class `active` to your link **will not** make the `:active` state activate. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active for more info about how it works.

If you want to mark the currently active link in the markup, just set the regular classes on the link you want to:

```
<a href="#packages" class="navigation__link border-b-2 bg-white border-gray-200">
  Packages
</a>
<a href="#containers" class="navigation__link border-b-2 bg-white border-red-500 bg-red-200 active">
  Containers
</a>
<a href="#envelopes" class="navigation__link border-b-2 bg-white border-gray-200">
  Envelopes
</a>
```

Comment: You're right. I completely forgot i had asked a question here... but yes, what i wanted was to be able to style some links (menu tabs) when the corresponding section was shown on the page. Which i could easily do in CSS (applying a style to .navigation__link.active). Nothing to do with the :active state, so I did not even need to extend variants at all. Thanks for your time.